# how to use GetValue() in wxpython?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to save a value to a variable when user puts it in.
I have search much and found that I have to use `GetValue()` but how? 
Can any one help me with my code?
`self.tc = wx.TextCtrl(p, pos=(1.4*L,90),size=(150,90))`
I don't know what a `class` is so use a method without it.
I have tried it but couldn't make it out.

```
self.tc = wx.TextCtrl(p, pos=(1.4*L,90),size=(150,90))
self.yy=(tc.GetValue())
```

I am a physics student and I sometimes have to do some coding.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading a tutorial on wxPython, such as the one on zetcode:

- http://zetcode.com/wxpython/

Or by going through some of the beginner examples on the wxPython wiki:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/

Then you'll know how to use a TextCtrl inside a class. Here's a simple example that you can learn a lot of concepts from:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Example")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        sizer.Add(self.text, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        button = wx.Button(panel, label="Get Value")
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
        sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onButton(self, event):
        """"""
        print self.text.GetValue()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This demonstrates how to add a TextCtrl and a Button object to a class. You will note that these two widgets are children of the wx.Panel, which is the sole child of the wx.Frame. We use a vertically oriented BoxSizer to hold the two child widgets and position them. We bind the button to an event handler (**onButton**) in which we grab the text control's contents and print it to standard out.

Comment: thankyou but actually it is not my matter of subject. i just want a command to do so. i am NOT a programmer rather a physics student.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you solved it (or abandoned) but this is for the record.

Python's issue, not wxPython's. The variable `tc` is declared as class' property by the use of `self` so you must stick with that all the way to the end of the class.

So you need to change `self.yy=(tc.GetValue())` to `self.yy = self.tc.GetValue()` (also a little typing polishment).